# Which permission in android manifest file trigger this permission?

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

Hi dear android developers!

When my installed on any android device it asked the following permission from the user.

[image]

I did not want anything from the user in my app, so I want to remove this permission from my app but I did not figure out the name of this permission in my android manifest.xml file. Please tells the name of this permission So I can remove it from my android manifest.xml file.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It would help if you post the manifest.xml file from your app. Probably it's the permission to write on storage.

Answer (score 3):

`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is the permission.  Butin general you should not request any permission you don't actually need.  If you have extras in your manifest, remove all of them.

Of course to get that popup you needed to ask for permissions at runtime.  So somewhere you probably are using it.